# Cypress should not.exist or not.be.visible

Tags: cypress, assertion

Because of - imo - poor page design, I've found myself having problems verify the visibility or non-existance of one or more elements on a page.

The problem is that some of the elements does not exist, while some of them have CSS property display:none. But the existing test code checks for not.exist, which makes the test fail. But I cannot change to not.be.visible, since then it will fail on the other elements.

So: Is it possible to do an OR in an assertion? Somthing like

```
cy.get('blabla').should('not.be.visible').or.cy.get('blabla').should('not.exist');
```

The above line compiles, but yields an undefined on the second part, so it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

(I don't consider the code architecture important - the question is basically the OR thing.)

```
page.sjekkAtDellaanFelterVises(2, 2, [
  DellaanFelter.formaal,
  DellaanFelter.opprinneligLaanebelop,
  DellaanFelter.utbetalingsdato,
  DellaanFelter.restlaanInnfridd,
]);

public sjekkAtDellaanFelterVisesALT(sakRad: number, delLanRad: number, felter: DellaanFelter[]) {
  this.sjekkFelter(felter, DellaanFelter, (felt: string) => this.delLanAccordionBody(sakRad, delLanRad).get(this.e2e(felt)));
}   

@ts-ignore
public sjekkFelterALT<T, E extends Node = HTMLElement>(felter: T[], enumType, lookupFn: (felt: string) => Chainable<JQuery<E>>) {
  this.valuesOfEnum(enumType).forEach(felt => {
    this.sjekkFelt(felt, felter, enumType, lookupFn);
  });
}

// @ts-ignore enumType fungerer fint i praksis ...
public sjekkFeltALT<T, E extends Node = HTMLElement>(felt: string, felter: T[], enumType, lookupFn: (felt: string) => Chainable<JQuery<E>>) {
  if (felter.some(feltSomSkalVises => enumType[feltSomSkalVises] == felt)) {
    lookupFn(felt).should('be.visible');
  } else {
    lookupFn(felt).should('not.exist');
  }
}
```

Or is the solution to try and check if the elements exists first, then if they do, check the visibility?

Answer (score 10):

You can use `cypress-if` plugin for elegant syntax. Follow your `cy.get()` with `.if()` combined with the visibility assertion, then `.else()` combined with existence assertion.

For example, if I have a single `<div>` on the page but it's not visible

```html
<div style="display:none">a</div>
```

Both these tests will pass

```js
cy.get('div')
  .if()
  .should('not.be.visible')   // passes
  .else()
  .should('not.exist')        // skipped

cy.get('span')
  .if()
  .should('not.be.visible')  // skipped
  .else()
  .should('not.exist')       // passes
```

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem, with some modals being destroyed (i.e. removed from the DOM) on close and others being just hidden.

I found a way to kinda emulate an `or` by adding the visibility check as a filter to the selection, then asserting non-existence:

```
cy.get('my-selector').filter(':visible').should('not.exist')
```

The error messages in case of failure are not as self-explanatory ("expected `:visible` to not exist") and you have to read the log a bit further to understand. If you don't need the separation between selector and filter you can combine the both to make get a nicer error message ("expected `my-selector:visible` to not exist"):

```
cy.get('my-selector:visible').should('not.exist')
```

Comment: But do you need the `:visible` if the element should not exist? Does it fail if a hidden version exists?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. As OP said: "The problem is that some of the elements does not exist, while some of them have CSS property display:none". The "not.exists" fails when the element is just hidden, the "not.be.visible" fails when the the element is not in the DOM. So in OP's case, neither would cover both those cases, hence the search for an or-combination.

Comment: I think your claim "kinda emulate an or" is not achieved with  `cy.get('my-selector:visible').should('not.exist')` - my expectation is it will ***only*** test for `not.exists`. Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, the error message will only mention "expect X not to exist". But "X" will be something along the lines of `my-selector:visible`, meaning "no visible `my-selector`s exist in the DOM", which was good enough to make my tests run and give enough feedback in case they fail. I'll see whether I can break it down into a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

- Use .should('not.be.visible') for elements that exist in the DOM but
  would not be visible to a fully sighted person.
- Use    .should('not.exist') for elements that do not exist in the
  DOM,    regardless of their visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help some of you. I've been working with Cypress for a while now and found these particular custom commands to be pretty useful. I hope they help you too. ( Check for visibility utilizes the checkExistence command as well. You can just use the cy.isVisible() command and it will automatically check if it's at least in the DOM before continuing ).

P.S. These commands are still being tweaked - be nice :)

Command for checking existence

```
/**
 * @param {String} errorMessage The error message you want to throw for the function if no arg is used
 */
const isRequired = (errorMessage = '--- Parameter is required! ---') => { throw new Error(errorMessage); };

/**
 * @description Check if an element, found through xpath selector, exists or not in the DOM
 * @param {String} xpath Required. Xpath to pass into the function to check if it exists in the DOM
 * @param {Object} ifFound Message to pass to cy.log() if found. Default message provided
 * @param {String} ifNotFound Message to pass to cy.log() if not found. Default message provided
 * @returns Boolean. True if found, False if not found
 * @example cy.checkExistence("xpath here", "Found it!", "Did not find it!").then(result=>{if(result==true){ // do something } else { // do something else }})
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('checkExistence',(xpath=isRequired(), ifFound, ifNotFound )=>{
  return cy.window().then((win) => {
    return (function(){
      let result = win.document.evaluate(xpath, win.document.body, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue
      if(result!=null && result!=undefined){
          if ( ifFound != undefined ) {
            cy.log( `_** ${ifFound} **_` );
          }
          return cy.wrap( true );                                     
      } else {
          if ( ifNotFound != undefined ) {
            cy.log( `_** ${ifNotFound} **_` );
          }
          return cy.wrap( false );
      }
    })();
  });
})
```

Command for checking visibility

```
/**
 * @param {String} errorMessage The error message you want to throw for the function if no arg is used
 */
const isRequired = (errorMessage = '--- Parameter is required! ---') => { throw new Error(errorMessage); };

/**
 * @description Check to see if an element is visible or not, using xpath selector or JQuery element
 * @param {String} Xpath Xpath string
 * @param {Boolean} waitForVisibility Optional. False by default. Set to true to wait for element to become visible.
 * @param {Number} timeout Optional. Timeout for waitForVisibility param.
 * @returns Boolean. True if visible, False if not visible
 * @example cy.isVisible("//div").then(result=>{})
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('isVisible', (Xpath=isRequired(), waitForVisibility=false, timeout)=>{
  cy.checkExistence(Xpath).then(result=>{
    if(result==true){
      cy.xpath(Xpath).then($element => {
        if ($element.is(':visible')){
          return cy.wrap(true)
        } else {
          if(waitForVisibility===true){
            if(!timeout){
              cy.logSpecial('wave',3, `Must provide value for timeout. Recieved ${timeout}`, true)
            } else {
              cy.log(`Waiting for element to become visible within ${timeout / 1000} seconds...`, true).then(()=>{
                let accrued;
                let interval = 250;
                (function retry(){
                  if ($element.is(':visible')){
                    return cy.wrap(true)
                  } else {
                    accrued = accrued + interval;
                    if(accrued>=timeout){
                      cy.log(`Timeout waiting for element to become visible. Waited ${timeout / 1000} seconds.`)
                      return cy.wrap(false)
                    } else {
                      cy.wait(interval)
                      cy.wrap(retry())
                    }
                  }
                })();
              })
            }
          } else {
            return cy.wrap(false)
          }
        }
      })
    } else {
      cy.log(`Element does not exist in the DOM. Skipping visibility check...`).then(()=>{
        if(throwError==true){
         throw new Error (`Element of xpath ${Xpath} was not visible.`)
        }
        return cy.wrap(false)
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The tl;dr is that there isn't going to be a simple solution here -- Cypress' `get` command has assertions, so you can't easily catch or eat those exceptions. If you try to get an element that doesn't exist, Cypress will have a failed assertion. Unfortunately, the best case would be to have deterministic behavior for each assertion.

[More info on *why* Cypress behaves this way here.](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Error-Recovery)

I think your best case for doing this would be to write a custom Chai assertion, but I don't have any experience in doing anything like that. [Here is Chai's documentation on doing so.](https://www.chaijs.com/guide/helpers/)

If you wanted to simplify your code, but knew which elements should not exist and which elements should not be visible, you could write a custom command to handle that.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('notExistOrNotVisible', (selector, isNotExist) => {
  cy.get(selector).should(isNotExist ? 'not.exist' : 'not.be.visible');
});

cy.notExistOrNotVisible('foo', true); // asserts that `foo` does not exist
cy.notExistOrNotVisible('bar', false); // asserts that `bar` is not visible
```

I arbitrarily made not exist the positive case, but you could switch that and the logic in the `should`.

Comment: Hey, the custom command sounds like a good solution. Much easier than the Chai assertion, for sure. I do know - in this case - which elements will not exist and which will not be visible, so it should do for this case :-)

Comment: Awesome, glad it will work for you. I wasn't sure from your question if you were going to be unsure for most of them and wanted a catchall function.

Comment: How do I add the command, though? I've added it to the commands.ts file, rebuilt and refreshed the project. But it still says TS2339: Property 'notExistOrNotVisible' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'.

Comment: You'll need to add it to the Cypress namespace.  https://medium.com/@gghalistan/adding-custom-commands-to-cypress-typescript-28d23f90c2fd

Answer (score -1):

```
cy.get('my-selector').should($el => {
  expect($el.length == 0 || !$el.is(":visible"), "does not exist or is not visible").to.be.true;
})
```

Edit: @“-1” Sorry, I think there was a bug (should be `!$el.is(":visible")` not `!$el.is("visible")`). Fixed it now.